# SQL Server Generate Scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, scripting

I need to find a way to generate insert select scripts for a set of tables. The `Generate Scripts Task` in SSMS 2008 seems to generate insert values statements. I could just generate them using some of the system views but would prefer to functionality for this already in SSMS

Thanks

Comment: And where do you want to insert data? Same table? Different DB?

Comment: Anyhow - something like `SELECT 'INSERT INTO ' + name + '_New SELECT * FROM ' + name FROM sys.tables` is your best option here.

Comment: thanks again Nenad. I figured I might end up using doing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do? Generate script for Insert or Select? Right click on the table choose 'Script table as' and choose what you want to do

Comment: I need something like: insert instanceA.schema.table_A(col1,col2) select col1,col2 from instanceB.schema.table_A

Answer (score 0):

In Object Explorer, pick your database, use `Tasks > Generate Scripts..` and then click on the `Advanced Options` button:

[image]

In the dialog that comes up, you can pick what to script - schema only, data only or schema and data:

[image]

Comment: thanks Marc. I was aware of this way but it generates one insert..values statement per row (huge file for large table) and I was looking for a single insert..select command instead. I think I will have to use the sys.tables view.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this script:

```
--assuming only the db instance differs
declare  @otherDB varchar(100) = 'instanceB'
declare @thisDB varchar(100) = db_name()

select 
'INSERT INTO ' +  @otherDB + '.' + s.name + '.' + t.name + 
' SELECT * FROM ' + @thisDB + '.' + s.name + '.' + t.name 
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
where t.is_ms_shipped = 0
```